# iOS map-kit view only certain region in map

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview

I'm new to iOS map-kit, even though i have loaded mapview in my app using the following code

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
zoomLocation.latitude = 39.281516;
zoomLocation.longitude= -76.580806;
 // 2
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);
// 3
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [_mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];                
// 4
[_mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

I want to allow user only to view a **certain region not the whole world** in the map, For example i take america, i want to allow user **to view only america in the map**, where he can't able to view any other places. What have to do to achieve this.. Needs your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the zoom level to a particular country or a particular region..... i think you must have a look at [this](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/).... that helped me when i was trapped in such kind of confusion... i hope that might help you too....